# Why replace `capitalize` with a check for whether it is lowercase before `titlecase` is called?

Tags: string, kotlin, title-case

When using Kotlin 1.5, Android Studio warns that `String.capitalize` is deprecated.

The suggested replacement is:

```kotlin
myString.replaceFirstChar { if (it.isLowerCase()) it.titlecase(Locale.getDefault()) else it.toString() })
```

Why is the check for `isLowerCase` neccessary?

Why can't I just do this:

```kotlin
myString.replaceFirstChar { it.titlecase(Locale.getDefault()) })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quote from the [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43023):

> Additionally, users may have varied expectations about the behavior of `fun String.capitalize(): String`, and the expectations do not always coincide with what we have implemented (see the [KEEP](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/223) discussion). The function titlecases the first char of the receiver `String` only if it is a lower case letter. For instance, the result of `"Ǆ".capitalize()` is `"Ǆ"`, while `"ǆ".capitalize()` is `"ǅ"`. Given the different expectations, we would like to introduce replaceFirstChar function to let users code exactly what they want.

> The replacements are verbose, but preserve the behavior as close as possible. The resulting code can be simplified further if a more simple behavior is desired, for example to `String.replaceFirstChar { it.uppercaseChar() }`.

---

*Below is the original answer based on my thoughts. Please also check comment as there is a good note regarding `ﬀ`:*

I suppose this is because they wanted to replicate original behavior. Currently `capitalize` [implemented](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/46d5e974dfb1c6449d235b7e322fddba8370e15d/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/text/StringsJVM.kt#L740) as:

```
public fun String.capitalize(locale: Locale): String {
    if (isNotEmpty()) {
        val firstChar = this[0]
        if (firstChar.isLowerCase()) {
            return buildString {
                val titleChar = firstChar.titlecaseChar()
                if (titleChar != firstChar.uppercaseChar()) {
                    append(titleChar)
                } else {
                    append(this@capitalize.substring(0, 1).uppercase(locale))
                }
                append(this@capitalize.substring(1))
            }
        }
    }
    return this
}
```

Also, according to the note:

> The title case of a character is usually the same as its upper case with several exceptions.

There are some corner cases:

```
fun check(x: String) {
    println(x.capitalize())
    println(x.replaceFirstChar { if (it.isLowerCase()) it.titlecase() else it.toString() })
    println(x.replaceFirstChar { it.titlecase() })
}

fun main() {
    check("ǳ")
    check("Ǳ")
}
```

Output ([playground](https://pl.kotl.in/X1X850MPh)):

```
ǲ
ǲ
ǲ
Ǳ
Ǳ
ǲ
```

Comment: Note that even though this fix tries to replicate the same behaviour as `capitalize`. They are not exactly the same. For the ligature `ﬀ`, `capitalized` returns `FF`, whereas the fix returns `Ff`. Not saying that you should still use `capitalize`! I think the latter result makes more sense.

Comment: Great point! Btw I also found a ticket for this change - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43023